# Not able to kill the cmd through subprocess module in python

Tags: python, subprocess

i am trying to invoke a command prompt and run some commands on it.
However when i am trying to close it through **kill()** or **terminate ()** , the cmd window does not get closed

Below is my code

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
test=Popen(["cmd","/K","appium -p 4723"],creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) 
sleep(10)
test.kill()
```

Comment: If I see that right you have a "chained" command that runs `cmd` which then runs an other command in an additional process. `test.kill()` will then kill the `cmd` process only. Depending on how the relation between the process is, the child might survive that.

Comment: @Klaus..Yes u r right !! i want to kill all the processes related to "test" object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run another subprocess and kill by PID:

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
test=Popen(["cmd","/K","appium -p 4723"],creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) 
pid = test.pid
sleep(10)

subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID %i' % pid)  # force kill and kill all child processes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im make.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = 'kill -%d %d' % (signal.SIGINT, os.getpid())
subprocess.call(cmd.split())
```

This will kill the current processes

Comment: it gives me error WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: have you set your python path correctly,  if not then this issues are caused

Comment: or else add `shell=True` to subprocess call like `subprocess.call(cmd.split(), shell=True)` @pankajmishra